# DataGrip column picker

Tags: datagrip

Is it possible to use a column picker in JetBrains DataGrip? I was not able to use this feature in DataGrip. For instance, sql complete contains this feature: [sql complete column picker image](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/images/T-SQL_Context/img55-SELECT%20COLUMN%20PICKER.png).

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean? You want just to select columns from the list?

Comment: Yes I want to select columns from a list like in the picture link. On the picture link there are check boxes for each column, thus you can open the pop-up once and select all necessary columns and press enter and all columns will be loaded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, there is no feature like this in DataGrip. I can offer you a couple of workflows:

— Use code completion, it is really fast. Once you have the table in your query (typing *SEL → Tab* activates *Live Template* for SELECT query), start typing column names in the list and completion will prompt you column names.

— Use wildcard and then expand it by *Alt+Enter → Expand column list*. Yo will get the whole column list, just remove unnecessary ones.

— If you need to have a result with some columns, not all of them, press *Ctrl+F12* on the result-set. Then you'll get a popup where you can show/hide columns with *Space*. Notice, that text speed search works there as well. See [Operations with columns in the structure view](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/viewing-query-results.html?keymap=primary_windows#using_structure_view).

All of them are shown in the attached gif file.

[image]

Comment: Are they plans to add the column picker feature to DataGrip? TOAD also has this feature and it's quite useful.

Comment: Can you please explain, why code completion for columns isn't useful? Is it easier to click on checkboxes? Or you just don't remember column names?

Comment: For tables or views that have many columns trying to explore data and build SQL, not all column names are necessarily known upfront. Even if they were known, in order to select, say, 4 or 5 columns of interest from a query that returns many columns with the * selection the current DataGrip workflow is not as efficient to me as a developer than being able to select checkboxes for columns of interest. The current DataGrip workflow to accomplish this feels a little backward.

Comment: @moscas, can the `Expand column list` feature be somehow forced to generate single line list instead of multiline?

Comment: @Vadzim yes, please go to Code Style options and set: 'New line after each selected item' to OFF and 'New line after select' to NEVER.

Comment: Now we also have postfix completion to get all columns from the table: https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/whatsnew/#code-completion

Comment: Also you can drag-n-drop the needed columns from the database tree.